# How to send mail specific gridview rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView with following columns

[image: Refer image for gridview columns]

When the status is red, I want to send mail of that specific column. Any idea how can I select/filter rows which have status red and send those rows in mail? Please help.

Any ideas are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

How are the rows bound to the gridview. Cant you just get those items and based on the status send those rows to an email?

Your question is a bit vague so be a bit more specific

Comment: Rows are coming from xml file. Then I'm pinging the url. IF ping success then status is green and if ping failed then status is RED.

Comment: Best to deserialize the xml to objects where you can directly read the status and decide on sending emails. This can be done before or after binding to the grid view. See xml deserialize example here http://stackoverflow.com/q/25959912/4624113